# Make redirection with param in django backend app and to react frontend app

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I want to make a redirection with param from django back-end app to react front-end app component and read param.

How can I do this? I'm struggling with this, it gives me Page not found.

My redirection code in django back-end view is :

```
 return redirect('http://localhost:3000/auth/new-password/',  {'uid': uid, 'token': token})
```

and my route to target component is :

```
 <Layout
      exact
      path="/auth/new-password/:uid/:token/"
      component={ResetPasswordConfirm}
    />
```

Thanks for help.